# Grabbing XML from javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

```
<SearchResults>
<error>Search term too small minimum 3 characters</error>
</SearchResults>
```

How can i grab the contents of `<error>` and print/store them.

At the moment i am counting them with

```
$(xml).find("Error").each(function()
{
  errorsFound++; 
}
```

For other reasons

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/ gives more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xy9t7/1/

```
var errorsFound = 0; 
$("<SearchResults><error>Search term too small minimum 3 characters</error></SearchResults>").find("error").each(function(){
    errorsFound++;
});
alert(errorsFound);
```

Could be that you're searching for Error instead of error (note the capitalization)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your javascript code like this:

```
$(xml).find("Error").each( function( index, element )
{
  var content = element.html();
  errorsFound++; 
}
```